# I seem to be getting an incorrect tweet count with my code

Tags: python, twitter

For some reason, I'm only getting 100 tweets from this code. According to the Twitter API, I believe I should be getting 1500.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Specifically the issue in question is this:

```
twiturl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + urlinfo + "&rpp=99&page=15" + "&since_id=" + str(tweetdate)

for x in arg1:
                        urlinfo = x[2]
                        idnum = int(x[1])
                        name = x[0]
                        twiturl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + urlinfo + "&rpp=99&page=15" + "&since_id=" + str(tweetdate)
                        response = urllib2.urlopen(twiturl)
                        twitseek = simplejson.load(response)
                        twitsearch = twitseek['results']
                        tweets = [x['text'] for x in twitsearch]
                        tweetlist = [tweets, name]
                        namelist.append(tweetlist)
```

The item that should be in x[2] is just a word or phrase like "I am" or "I am feeling" changed into a url friendly encoding

Answer (score 3):

The docs for the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) state:

> **rpp** (optional): The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of
>   100.

and

> **page** (optional): The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max
>   of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page).

Accordingly, you should make multiple requests, each with a different page number for up to 100 tweets for each request:

```
import urllib, json

twiturl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%s&rpp=99&page=%d"

def getmanytweets(topic):
    'Return a list of upto 1500 tweets'
    results = []
    for page in range(1, 16):
        u = urllib.urlopen(twiturl % (topic, page))
        data = u.read()
        u.close()
        t = json.loads(data)
        results += t['results']
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(getmanytweets('obama'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of results returned on a single page of results is 100. In order to get all results, you need to 'page' through them by using the `next_page` URL that is included in the response (see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) for the documentation). You can then loop through the responses, calling the `next_page` argument of each one until the argument is no longer present (indicating that you have collected all of the results).

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2


# General query stub
url_stub = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json'

# Parameters to pass
params = {
    'q': 'tennis',
    'rpp': 100,
    'result_type': 'mixed'
    }

# Variable to store our results
results = []

# Outside of our loop, we pull the first page of results
# The '?' is included in the 'next_page' parameter we receive
# later, so here we manually add it
resp = urllib2.urlopen('{0}?{1}'.format(url_stub, urllib.urlencode(params)))
contents = json.loads(resp.read())
results.extend(contents['results'])

# Now we loop until there is either no longer a 'next_page' variable
# or until we max out our number of results
while 'next_page' in contents:

  # Print some random information
  print 'Page {0}: {1} results'.format(
      contents['page'], len(contents['results']))

  # Capture the HTTPError that will appear once the results have maxed
  try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url_stub + contents['next_page'])
  except urllib2.HTTPError:
    print 'No mas'
    break

  # Load our new contents
  contents = json.loads(resp.read())

  # Extend our results
  results.extend(contents['results'])

# Print out how many results we received
print len(results)
```

Output:

```
Page 1: 103 results
Page 2: 99 results
Page 3: 100 results
Page 4: 100 results
Page 5: 100 results
Page 6: 100 results
Page 7: 100 results
Page 8: 99 results
Page 9: 98 results
Page 10: 95 results
Page 11: 100 results
Page 12: 99 results
Page 13: 99 results
Page 14: 100 results
Page 15: 100 results
No mas
1492
```